# Changing uiLabel value on field change Swift (newbie)

Tags: swift, uilabel, editing

Disclaimer: First iOS/ Swift app and following a tutorial.

I am trying to update the value of a uilabel based on what I enter in the uiField. In the debugger I see it entering the onEditingChanged() but the values of the label never change... No errors thrown. Also, the initial assignment to tipLabel.text = "$0.00" and totalLabel.text = "$0.00" works fine...

Any suggestions what may be wrong?

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  tips
//
//  Created by Jonida Cali on 12/13/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jonida Cali. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var amountField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tipLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tipLabel.text = "$0.00"
    totalLabel.text = "$0.00"

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func onEditingChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("changed")
    var billAmount = (amountField.text as NSString).doubleValue
    var tip  = billAmount*0.2
    var total = billAmount + tip


    tipLabel.text = String(format: "$%.2f", tip)
    totalLabel.text = String(format: "$%.2f",total)
}

}
```

Comment: If you do a `println(billAmount)` in `onEditingChanged` does it show the correct value?

Comment: Actually no - it returns 0.0... and when I do println(amountField) it returns an empty line...

Comment: is `amountField` linked correctly in storyboard?

Comment: I deleted the amountField outlet and added it again and that fixed it... An newbie's confusion!!! :S

Comment: Good to know it's an easy fix :)